# Convert String to a Date object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timezone, momentjs

In my Javascript application, I want to convert a string to an actual Date object.

My string is something like this; '2023-06-16 09-25-41'

Then I convert it to a Date with a desired format using moment.js library;

```
const dateStr = moment('2023-06-16 09-25-41', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); 
return new Date(dateStr);
```

which gives output; *Fri Jun 16 2023 09:25:41 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)*

The problem is that I want this date to be in UTC instead of GMT+03:00, so that it will still be **09:25:41** when I process this in my backend application. But I'm getting **06:25:41** instead right now.

So my question is, how can I convert my string to a Date object while keeping it in UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the time and add the offset, add the two and pass the result to a `Date` constructor.

```js
const dateStr = moment('2023-06-16 09-25-41', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); 
let date = new Date(dateStr);
console.log(new Date(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I needed to extract the offset instead of adding it, but it worked as expected, thanks.

Comment: @josh thanks for pointing that out, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.utc()` method in `moment.js`. Also, you can use `toDate()` instead of the additional `Date()` constructor.

```
const date = moment('2023-06-16 09-25-41', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
                  .utc()
                  .toDate();
```

**Also**
If you just start to use `moment.js` in your project, Please find some modern alternatives like [Date-fns](https://date-fns.org/). Here is [why?](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)